# NETunnelProviderSession startTunnel() doesn't start VPN connection

Tags: ios, swift, vpn, networkextension, nevpnmanager

So im using `PIATunnel` library to start a VPN connection. The best I have managed to get so far is trying to connect to a VPN server which immediately gets disconnected. 
I want to be able to debug the issue and find out what happens after calling the `startTunnel()`. I can only monitor the connectivity through the notification center observer, but i dont know whats causing the connection problem that I immediately get disconnected. On server side I don't see my IP address so for that reason im sure the iOS device is not making the connection.

Im basically running the Demo app from this repo: https://github.com/pia-foss/tunnel-apple/tree/master/Demo

What im uncertain of is that in order to debug the VPN tunnel do I need to run the Network Extension target? Can I debug using the containing app's target? I have tried both and when I override the init() for the `NEPacketTunnelProvider` subclass when running the extension target likde this:

```
override init() {
   os_log("QQQ PIATunnelProvider: init")
   super.init()
}
```

I don't see the log message (for my iPhone) in `Console` app.